# Xcode 4.3.2 and iOS 5.1.1 + jailbreak: App installs but crash on launch

Tags: xcode, crash, xcode4.3, jailbreak

I don't have the Apple 79€/year account. In iOS 5.0 and Xcode 4.2.1 I changed SDKSettings.plist ecc... And it works. In iOS 5.1.1 and Xcode 4.3.2 no, I already changed settings ecc but don't work, the app installs on device but crash on launch... How can I run my app on device without crashes? Thanks, and sorry for my english.

Comment: What error do you get when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before on a jailbroken device. You have a few solutions depending on the exact issue. First you can install app sync in order to allow unsigned code to work on your device if you are not using a valid code signing identity. The second option is to actually get a valid code signing identity along with the provision profile so you can run the application correctly. This involves paying for the developer program so this may not be the best option.

Last is a very common issue with jailbroken devices. Which is that you will receive an error such as "failed to get the task for process xxxxx". This tends to happen a lot with jailbroken devices. This is because Xcode notices you are not using a provision profile that is required to report error logs. All you have to do is launch the application again on the device and everything should work.

This is just Xcode not being able to fully launch your application because of the missing provision profile so it results in a crash. If none of these solutions solve your problem please post a more detailed explanation of the issue you are having.